# Augmenting Map<String, Long> value results in java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, servlets

I'm working on a web app that requires ordering the the languages a given GitHub user uses across all repositories from most used language to least used language. As part of this process I do the following:

CreateNewUser.java

```
            //store a mapping of languages to bytes written in that language
            Map<String, Long> allLangs = new HashMap<>();

            //get all repositories for the user
            Map<String, GHRepository> repositories = github.getMyself().getRepositories();

            //loop through each repository
            for (String repo : repositories.keySet()) {

                //get languages specific to repository mapped to bytes written in languages
                Map<String, Long> languages = repositories.get(repo).listLanguages();

                //loop through languages in repository
                for (String lang : languages.keySet()) {

                    //if the global language map contains the key
                    if (allLangs.containsKey(lang)) {
                        //add the value for this repository to the total bytes written
//**exception is thrown here**
                        allLangs.replace(lang, languages.get(lang) + allLangs.get(lang)); //line 73
                    } else {
                        //just add the number of bytes written
                        allLangs.put(lang, languages.get(lang));
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I run the application the following exception is thrown:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at Application.CreateNewUser.processRequest(CreateNewUser.java:73)
at Application.CreateNewUser.doGet(CreateNewUser.java:117)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried converting the value `languages.get(lang) + allLangs.get(lang)` on the line marked as `//**exception is thrown here**` (line 73) to a `Long` using several methods but have had no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you seem to have stored `Integer` values in a `Map` which you are trying to use as `Long`s.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, you were correct. I checked out the source code of the GitHub API Java library I was using and fixed the issue.